# When does cmake need to be reconfigured？

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I'm reading the cmake tutorial.
In the [build and run] of exercise 2, it said:

> Let's build our project again. As before, we already created a build
> directory and ran CMake so we can skip to the build step

Why does it no longer need the configure step, after all "Cmake --build ." command is under the build directory, not in the source directory.I know the configure step will generate the makefile, does the makefile detect changes to the file CMakeLists.txt? If so, what does that line of commands in the Makefile look like?
Under what circumstances do I need to reconfigure?

Comment: Yes, the generated build project files (whatever they are: makefiles, ninja, Visual Studio projects, Xcode projects, etc.) contains code to detect when cmakelists.txt files have been changed and re-run cmake.  As to "what that line of commands in the makefile looks like", who knows?  Makefiles generated by cmake are not human-readable and generally completely impenetrable.  They are best treated as a black-box and never opened or examined.

Comment: I just checked for the Ninja generator: `build.ninja` is a target like any other. It depends on all files in the CMake installation. The rule to remake it is called `RERUN_CMAKE` .. which does what you think it does.